# JUnit /TestNG check for catched Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, junit, try-catch, testng

i have the following problem:
Our java software takes incoming xml-files and parse / validate / makes some magic. Because it's a 24/7 software it's designed to resist single faults, by ignoring single files and proceeding to the next.

I want to know if there is a possible solution to test units e.g with JUnit or TestNG for already catched exceptions.

For example if have a class and function like this

```
public class ExceptionTest {
        public static void throwEx() {
           try {
                int i = 1 / 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Now i want to test if any Exception is catched. If so the test should fail. On the other hand, if i expect certain types of exceptions, the test should succeed.

```
public class TSTException {
    @Test
    public void testExceptionThrown() {
        ExceptionTest.throwEx();
        assert ("ExceptionsCatched.size()", 0)
    }
}
```

I know i could edit my code to provide some kind of global variables like `boolean success = true` and check those but i am interested if there is another possible solution for my problem.

Thanks,
Dominik

Comment: Your code does nothing. Could you publish some code that looks more real. This code has no meaning to be tested.

Comment: My example code does exactly what i try to find out. I have a function somewhere in my projekt (in some nested calls) which throws a exception. This exception is caught by the try and catch block (in the same function or in an parent function), but in my test i want to know if such a exception is thrown.

Comment: If you have some void method, then this void method should change the state of the object or delegate the method call to some service etc. That's what you need to test. If your method throws the exceptions, than it means that state wasn't changed or service method wasn't call. Test this, not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to modify the code You could wrap the class containing the logic and catch the exception in the wrapper class.
something like this:

```
public class SomeService{
    public void doSomething() {
            int i = 1 / 0;
    }
}

public class SomeServiceCatchExceptionWrapper{
    private SomeService someService;
    public void doSomething() {
       try {
           someService.doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So this way you can test both classes individually.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not possible without restructure the whole project. Is there no other possibility to check if Exceptions are caught?